# Kotlin -> Timestamp of today's date at a specific time

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get the timestamp of today's date at 4am. So when the API is called, on that day --4am.
I use offsetDateTime.now(), to get the current time, but is there a way to add a parameter to give me the timestamp of today's date at a specific hour >

```
  val now = OffsetDateTime.now()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `OffsetDateTime`'s `withX` functions to override specific fields in the date time:

```kotlin
val todayAt4am = OffsetDateTime.now()
    .withHour(4)
    .withMinute(0)
    .withSecond(0)
    .withNano(0)
```

Or more concisely using `truncatedTo`:

```kotlin
val todayAt4am = OffsetDateTime.now()
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS) // sets smaller units to 0
    .withHour(4)
```